# Freezing layers in pre-trained bert model

Tags: pytorch

[image: Pre Trained BERT Model]

How to freeze the last two layers in the above pre-trained model (dropout and classifier layers)? So that when the model is run, I will get a dense layer as output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would like to point you to the definition of [BertForSequenceClassification](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/transformers/modeling_bert.py#L849) and you can easily avoid the dropout and classifier by using:

```
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", num_labels=2)
model.bert() # this will give you the dense layer output
```

Why you can do the above? If you take a look at the constructor of BertForSequenceClassification:

```
def __init__(self, config):
    super(BertForSequenceClassification, self).__init__(config)
    self.num_labels = config.num_labels

    self.bert = BertModel(config)
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(config.hidden_dropout_prob)
    self.classifier = nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, self.config.num_labels)

    self.init_weights()
```

As you can see, you just want to ignore the `dropout` and `classifier` layers.

One more thing, freezing a layer and removing a layer are two different things. In your question, you mentioned that you want to freeze the classifier layer but freezing a layer will not help you to avoid it. Freezing means, you do not want to train the layer.

Comment: excuse me where can i write those lines `model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", num_labels=2)
model.bert() # this will give you the dense layer output` ?

Answer (score 4):

You already have dense layer as output (`Linear`).

There is no need to freeze `dropout` as it only scales activation during training.
You can set it to `evaluation` mode (essentially this layer will do nothing afterwards), by issuing:

```
model.dropout.eval()
```

Though it will be changed if the whole model is set to `train` via `model.train()`, so keep an eye on that.

To freeze last layer's weights you can issue:

```
model.classifier.weight.requires_grad_(False)
```

(or `bias` if that's what you are after)

If you want to change last layer to another shape instead of `(768, 2)` just overwrite it with another module, e.g.

```
model.classifier = torch.nn.Linear(768, 10)
```

For output tensor of size `10` (input shape has to be exactly as is specified in the model, hence `768`)

Comment: where can i write this line `model.classifier.weight.requires_grad_(False)` ?